# Saving a file client side with Meteor

Tags: javascript, xml, file, meteor, save

I was looking around trying to find a solution but was unable one. What I want is the take whatever the user enters into text fields and save those into an xml file. Then I want to prompt the user to save that file.

What I mean is to get the info from many different input fields through `document.getElementById('id').value` and put that into the file.

For example:`<lessonname>document.getElementById('lessonname').value</lessonname>\n`

Comment: did you get a workaround?